# What is considered a spammable offense on AskUbuntu?

Tags: discussion

I am new to this Ubuntu forum but not to using Ubuntu as much. I recently made a first post asking a question on Ubuntu security and that was all. I was given an email that I was suspended (15 pts) for spam for a personal website I placed in my profile page in the webpage slot. For reference http://JayCouture.com I am including this as a reference only,  as there is not anything you can sign up for or to be spammed on this page in my view.

Could this be done in error or automatically be a errant anti-spam bot? I hesitate on making another forum membership at this point because this would be dishonest without gaining more info on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what this site has to do with the ubuntuforums.org, but I think the following explains what happened:

http://bapoumba.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/ubuntuforums-changes-on-accounts-permissions/

"Fact is several of us in the forums Staff team had to spend at least one   hour a day cleaning after spammers. Spammers tactic: fill profile fields with spam links, upload spam pics as avatar, even create user albums with the pics, comment on other regular users profiles, send PMs or emails etc. All of these are sneaky as we need to examine each profile to find them out."

There is also a related forum announcement:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836816